# What are the steps to find an eigenbasis?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example, I am confused about they got from the rref of the matrix to the basis of the eigenspace...
[image]

Comment: Do you know how to find the nullspace (kernel) of a matrix?

Comment: thanks a lot. didn't know that was a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Row reduction says the eigenspace satisfies the equation $x=2y-z$. Thus it is isomorphic to $\mathbf R^2$,  and the basis of the eigenspace is the image of the canonical basis of $\mathbf R^2$.